# sudo & chown command not found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line, terminal

I have a rails project which I think has been created as root. I want to change the permissions so that the owner is not root but my user.

I found a command here on stackoverflow to achieve this.

```
sudo chown -R $(username):$(username) Directoryname
```

So to change it so that my user owns it I am running this:

```
sudo chown -R $(Jack):$(Jack) APIClient
```

However I get the error:

```
 sudo: chown: command not found
```

If i just run chown without sudo I get:

```
zsh: command not found: chown
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? I think it may be to do with my zsh but not sure.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you can do it with command "chmod" too. isn't it?

Comment: Take a look this link : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/

Comment: @SSR I've seen that link but like above running any of those gives me chown command not found??

Comment: run `whereis sudo chown` and check if you have these paths added to your `$PATH` variable (you can display it by running `echo $PATH`)

Comment: @kaman no they're not. How do I go about adding them in to my $PATH? p.s thanks for the help.

Comment: You probably have `sudo` path already added since it's (or at least should be)in the same directory as `whereis`. You probably need to add `/usr/sbin` dir and I assume you run osx so just `echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin" >> ~/.bash_profile` (you may need to close and open your terminal again to see any effect)

Comment: If I could upvote this 100x I would. @kaman thanks so much.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So @kaman helped me fix the problem in the comments above.

Turns out I didn't have the links to chown in my $PATH variable.

To fix this I added the following to my `.zshrc` file. However as kaman has put in the comments above If you're running bash just put it in the `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin"
```

Thanks kaman and hope this helps anyone else who gets the same error.

Comment: I did this change, but then PING stopped working.  Any thoughts?